# Standard error of the estimated value

Tags: statistics

I have a variable with an estimated value $\frac{1}{5}(4a+b+c+d+e)$ and **variance** $\frac{1}{5}(a-b-c-d-e)^2$. And in the solution of a related problem I read that the standard error of the estimated value is $\sqrt{\frac{4}{5}\times \text{variance}}$.

Could someone tell me where the factor $\frac{4}{5}$ comes from?

Answer (score 0):

The standard error of the estimated value is $s=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1}\cdot TSS}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}}\cdot \sqrt{TSS} \quad (1)$

TTS is the Total sum of squares.

The standard deviation is $\sigma =\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\cdot TSS}=\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\cdot \sqrt{TSS} \quad (2)$

Dividing (1) by (2)

$\frac{s}{\sigma}= \frac{\sqrt{ n}}{\sqrt{n-1}}$

Thus $s=\frac{\sqrt {n}}{\sqrt{n-1}}\cdot \sigma=\frac{\sqrt{ n}}{\sqrt{n-1}}\cdot \sqrt{ \sigma ^2}=\sqrt{\frac{n}{n-1}\cdot \sigma ^2}$

In your case it should be $\sqrt{\color{red}{\frac{5}{4}}\cdot \texttt{variance}}$.

I think it is a typo.